# Objective C - Unit testing target doesn't recognize classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I created a unit test target, that has a dependency on my main target.
Correct me if I'm wrong but adding a dependency should add all the classes from my main target to the unit test target.
Importing classes in unit test target works, but as soon as I try to use these classes in my test target I get the following compile error:

**Apple Match-O Linker (ID) Error - _OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginViewcontroller", referenced from:**

I know that I could manually add each file to my unit test target but that doesn't seem to be the proper way. Anyone know why adding the dependency doesn't work as expected? Or any way to get around this issue?

I do **NOT** want to set a "Test Host".

Answer (score 0):

I have to correct you there: Adding a dependency should *not* add all the classes from yoru main target to the unit test target. It just causes your main target to be built. You additionally have to actually link to your main target.

**Update:** you can link to your target in the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase in the "Build Phases" tab.

Comment: Thanks, how can I link to the main target? Does it have to be done file by file, os is there a simpler way?

Comment: Updated my answer to say why.. HTH! :)

Comment: @StigBrautaset shouldn't your main target be a Static library to link as a binary to the test target ? There should be a difference between when you add a test target to a main target which is a static library and a ordinary iPhone application right ?

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, and I didn't want to add all the classes manually. So I ended up going with TestHost